# Skipping 0xff byte when using pandas read_csv

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, pandas, null

I am trying to read some log files from my boiler, but they are rather poorly formatted.

When I try to read the file(s) with

```
import pandas

print(pandas.read_csv('./data/CM120102.CSV', delimiter=';'))
```

I get

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 49: invalid start byte`

The csv header ends in a null byte for some reason.

https://gist.github.com/Ession/6e5bf67392276048c7bd

http://mathiasjost.com/CM120102.CSV <== this one should work (or rather not work)

Is there any way to read these files with pandas without fixing them first?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with 2.7 and 0.16.  File reads in fine and prints fine for me.

Comment: Did you copy the text or did you click on raw and download the file? If I copy the text from the site i don't get the null byte/error either. But when downloading I get the error.

Comment: I downloaded the RAW file and it opens fine in `pandas`. The NULL byte may be lost somewhere. That being said, it's probably better to fix the files separately and then use pandas if the error continues to happen.

Comment: have you tried the `encoding` parameter for read_csv? or do you know the real file encoding of the file?

Comment: Yeah I just tried It again. Now I don't get it either. Must be lost on the way. I would prefer not having to change the logs. But if there's no other way...

Comment: @MathiasJost I downloaded raw.

Comment: @Dyno Hongjun Fu I tried several encodings with no different result. I am pretty sure that it's utf-8 just badly written.

Comment: then i'd suggest provide your own reader to skip the bad bytes. open the file with `f = codecs.open("whatever.csv", error='ignore'); pandas.read_csv(f, delimiter=";")` https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html

Comment: @Dyno Hongjun Fu That sadly throws the same error. (It's errors='ignore' btw)

Comment: cannot reproduce your problem on Mac. on Linux, it reports a different problem... `pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 13 fields in line 3, saw 14`

Comment: What version of python / pandas are you using?

Comment: @Andy Hayden I am on Python 3.4.1 and Pandas 0.16.0

Comment: I got the reported problem on an iMac with pandas 0.16.0 and python 2.7. As others did not, there is something subtle happening here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would read it into a string. Then do some munging in python, before passing it off to pandas.read_csv. Example code follows.

```
# get the data as a python string
with open ("CM120102.CSV", "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()

# munge in python - get rid of the garbage in the input (lots of xff bytes)
import re
data = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.;:\n]', '', data) # get rid of the rubbish
data = data + '\n' # the very last one is missing?
data = re.sub(r';\n', r'\n', data) # last ; separator on line is problematic

# now let's suck into a pandas DataFrame
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), index_col=None, header=0,
    skipinitialspace=True, sep=';', parse_dates=True)
```

Comment: After changing `from StringIO import StringIO` to `from io import StringIO` for Python 3 this works perfectly! Thanks.